# How to merge points at center in Houdini

Tags: geometry, point, modeling, houdini

In Blender, if you hit M key and select Merge At Center, all the selected points will be merged into 1 point.

I want to ask how should I perform the same action in Houdini?

I research a lot and discovered that some people recommend using the Fuse Node, but I still cannot figure out what setting in the Fuse Node should it take to merge all points at center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

Use an ExtractCentroid Node, and set the Run Over option to Detail.

Comment: Found the solution here. https://forums.odforce.net/topic/14603-how-to-create-a-point-at-the-center-of-every-primitive-on-a-grid-sop/